# Quick and easy way to show whether a matrix is injective / surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I'm afraid there could be a task like that in my exam. What way would you recommend me if there was a quadratic matrix given, such as $A= \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 4\\ 
0 & 3 & 0\\ 
1 & 7 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$?

There are several (for me confusing) ways doing it I think.

The one we had in our readings is to check if the column vectors are linearly independent (or something like that :S). But I think this would only tell us whether the linear mapping is injective.

But I think there is another, faster way with rank? I hope you can explain with this example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But I think there is another, faster way with rank? I hope you can explain with this example?

For square matrices, you have both properties at once (or neither). If it has full rank, the matrix is *injective* **and** *surjective* (and thus *bijective*). You could check this by calculating the determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
2 & 0 & 4\\ 
0 & 3 & 0\\ 
1 & 7 & 2
\end{vmatrix} = 0 \implies \mbox{rank}\,A < 3$$
Hence the matrix is not injective/surjective.

---

In general for an $m \times n$-matrix $A$:

- If the matrix has full rank ($\mbox{rank}\,A = \min\left\{ m,n \right\}$), $A$ is:

  - **injective** if $m \ge n = \mbox{rank}\,A$, in that case $\dim \ker A = 0$;
  - **surjective** if $n \ge m = \mbox{rank}\,A$;
  - **bijective** if $m=n=\mbox{rank}\,A$.
- If the matrix does not have full rank ($\mbox{rank}\,A < \min\left\{ m,n \right\}$), $A$ is not injective/surjective.

---

See also:

- same matrix, different approach: [How do I show that a matrix is injective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319663/159845)
- for non-square matrices: [Matrix characterization of surjective and injective linear functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/949685/159845)

Comment: Thank you! For non-square matrix, could I also do this: If the dimension of the kernel $= 0 \Rightarrow$ injective. If rank = dimension of matrix $\Rightarrow$ surjective ?

Comment: @tenepolis Yes, I extended the answer a bit.